# Rails - Extend a Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, activemerchant

I want to add some functionality to the ActiveMerchant gem in order to test the PayPal Express gateway, a pull request has been attempted for this but was turned down on Github.

I want to add a single class to the ActiveMerchant Billing module:

```
module ActiveMerchant #:nodoc:
  module Billing #:nodoc:
    class PaypalBogusGateway < BogusGateway

      # some codes here

    end
  end
end
```

I have done this successfully by downloading and pulling the gem into my project locally and trhowing my new file in there:

```
#Gemfile
gem 'activemerchant', '1.34.1', path: "vendor/gems/activemerchant-1.34.1", require: 'active_merchant'
```

But of course, that's not the best idea because I'll have to manually pull any updates if I want them.

Is there any way I can add the class to their module using their gem that's been pulled from  the RubyGems source?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Putting it in the lib folder should work but my code requires some classes from the gem to inherit from, like:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/paypal/paypal_common_api'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/paypal/paypal_express_response'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/paypal_express_common'
```

replacing File.dirname(**FILE**) with wherever the gem is installed... This will be different across server environments right?

Comment: You should be able to add your new class to the lib directory of a rails app (or other location if not rails) and it should 'just work'

Comment: see edit, you got any ideaS? I think I need to know how gems are located on different systems after the bundle command.

Comment: yeah it's the final Rails 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to just fork the project on GitHub and add your changes to it. Even if it is just a single class. And then, in your `Gemfile`, do this:

```
gem "active_merchant", :git => "git://github.com/<your-user-name-here>/active_merchant.git"
```

Comment: Very good idea, thanks. For anyone else wanting to do similar -> https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo

Comment: this seems really extreme to me. forking a gem just to create a sub-class from one of the gems types; defeats the entire purpose of object oriented programming - reuse.

Comment: @house9 Agree. Nice answer :) Somehow, that thought never occurred to me. Your's should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @house9 - sorry I don't understand how this defeats OO programming? How is your answer any different? Using Git I can update the core and maintain my code's subclass because it will still extend from the core 's super class. Using your answer I would have to manually download and replace the core, am I right?

Comment: @AdamWaite - after thinking about this again - you are right it doesn't defeat OO - however you working against rubygems/bundler - these tools manage dependencies for you, but now you are managing them your self: "Would you fork rails just so you could inherit from ActiveRecord?" unlikely, but that appears to be what you are doing just so you can inherit from PaypalBogusGateway ?

Comment: Yeah exactly that but I don't know how my class can find the super class to inherit from - that's what the question sort of was meant to be in the first place

Answer (score 7):

Add activemerchant to the Gemfile, bundle install

In `config/application.rb` make sure lib is included in the autoload paths

```
# need to uncomment or add this to the configuration
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

place your class in a file using nested directories to match the modules

```
# lib/active_merchant/billing/paypal_bogus_gateway.rb
```

do NOT include any require statements in your bogus gateway, rails (via bundler should require everything from the Gemfile)

restart rails